# How to select a valid random value from drop down using NightwatchJS?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, testing, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to automate some UI testing with nightwatch.js, I need to select a random value from the drop down which looks like the code below.

```html
<select class="form-control" name="drop_ddl" id="drop_ddl">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

As of now I am using an approach where I have no reliability in case the random number I have selected doesn't exist in the drop down option values.

```js
  var drop_ddl=Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
  return this.client.click("#drop_ddl option[value='"+drop_ddl+"']");
```

In case the random number is say 6 which doesn't appear in the list it will fail the further tests.

Is there a way we can read the values to an array and then select randomly out of these available values only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`elements`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/elements.html) to get all the drop down options.

```
browser.elements('css selector', '#drop_ddl option', function(result) {
        return result.value.length;
    })
```

Now that you have the number of options, use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select a random option.

```
var drop_ddl=Math.floor((Math.random() * optionsLength) + 1);
 return this.client.click("#drop_ddl option:nth-child(drop_ddl)");
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used this approach and so far this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding sequential IDs to the options?

```
<select class="form-control" name="drop_ddl" id="drop_ddl">
<option id="1" value=""></option>
<option id="2" value="1">1</option>
<option id="3" value="2">2</option>
<option id="4" value="3">3</option>
<option id="5" value="4">4</option>
<option id="6" value="7">7</option>
<option id="7" value="8">8</option>
<option id="8" value="9">9</option>
<option id="9" value="11">11</option>
<option id="10" value="12">12</option>
</select>

<script>
var drop_ddl=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
$("#drop_ddl option[id='" + drop_ddl + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is, this data is dynamic in nature and depends on what all options are enabled or disabled from backend. Had that been case  I wouldn't been facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Came across similar case, when you have to select random **Radio button**. This is a bit tricky - you can't really use `:nth-child` selector, because bloody bastards could be spread all over the place. In this case you can use:

```
exports.command = function (selector, value) {
    this
        .elements('css selector', selector, res => {
            if (res.value.length) {
                let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.value.length);
                let el = res.value[random].ELEMENT;
                this.elementIdClick(el);
            }
        });
    return this;
};
```